# Working on GAE+Java - Contact forms and Comment box

Tags: html, google-app-engine, web, comments, contact-form

I created my website with some simple codes and design using Adobe Dw and hosted it on GAE. it's a very simple website, html files, images and external css... actually that's the extent of my knowledge when it comes to programming and I have no knowledge beyond simple html and css whatsoever!

I would like to receive comment from my users and I also I need to have a contact form which forwards the information to my email.

The second one, I guess, should be pretty easy and google turns a lot of results for free "form to email"

But for the comments, I need to be able to save it on the servers, on GAE.

I'm not sure how GAE works, but if I'm correct it should act just like any other server and allow me to write data too without having to login to my account and using Eclips!

Here is what I need to know:

How can I get comments (or any submitted data) from website users, save it to GAE servers and be able to modify it latter if needed.

Since I have no idea where should begin with this, it would be so much help to me even if you only tell what should I look for and what do I need.

I forgot to tell, I use Eclipse/Java to deploy my codes in the 'war' folder to GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the short answer is: yes GAE offers a data storing facility, and you can access it either via its [Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) or its [Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/)

The longer answer: you must learn how to write a component in either of these two languages, such that you can add it to your application, and it would be triggered by certain actions (such as submitting a form). With Java this would be a [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Comment: Thank you, at least now I have an idea about where should I start :)